# how to communicate with a router

Tags: python, telnet

I have written a script to perform telnet, which i wanted to use for sending commands to my Device Under Test (router).

My Telnet Script:

```
import sys, time, telnetlib

sys.path.insert(0, '/tmp')
import options

def telnet_connect():

        HOST = "%s" %options.DUT_telnet_ip
        PORT = "%s" %options.DUT_telnet_port
        username = "%s" %options.DUT_telnet_username
        password = "%s" %options.DUT_telnet_password

        tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT, 10)
        time.sleep(5)
        tn.write("\n")
        tn.read_until("login:", 2)
        tn.write(username)
        tn.read_until("Password:", 2)
        tn.write(password)
        tn.write("\n")
        response = tn.read_until("$", 5)
        return response

def telnet_close():
        response = tn.write("exit\n")
        return response
```

---

I want to use this script in another program which will check the version of the Router by telneting it. I expect a script which will call my above function to perform telnet and send other commands viz. "version" or "ls"

Comment: `tn` is undefined in `telnet_close()`. You probably want to pass the telnet instances around as a parameter. As is, this won't execute.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make this more like a class:

```
import sys, time, telnetlib

sys.path.insert(0, '/tmp')


class TelnetConnection():

    def init(self, HOST, PORT):

        self.tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT, 10)

    def connect(self, username, password):
        tn = self.tn
        tn.write("\n")
        tn.read_until("login:", 2)
        tn.write(username)
        tn.read_until("Password:", 2)
        tn.write(password)
        tn.write("\n")
        response = tn.read_until("$", 5)
        return response

    def close(self):
        tn = self.tn
        response = tn.write("exit\n")
        return response

# create here then a method to communicate as you wish
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
import options
HOST = "%s" %options.DUT_telnet_ip
PORT = "%s" %options.DUT_telnet_port
username = "%s" %options.DUT_telnet_username
password = "%s" %options.DUT_telnet_password
connection = TelnetConnection(HOST, PORT)
connection.connect(username, password)

connection.do_all_operations_you_want() # write your own method for that

connection.close()
```